# Booting problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, cuda

My Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo S510p very frequently boots to this screen and hangs:

[image: Ubuntu boot screen]

It is isn't always, sometimes it boots up to the lock screen, like normal, sometimes it just hangs at the above screen. A friend of mine ran into the same error, and he said it was probably because of the NVIDIA CUDA Driver.
Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem, It definitely was the CUDA (NIVIDIA) driver. All I did was uninstall the drivers via terminal, and voila!! My booting is back to normal.